# Javascript custom keyshortcut loop trouble

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new at this and was hoping one of you could help me? What I'm trying to do is write a key shortcut on my webpage, which works. I just don't know how I would exactly loop it to make said person be able to use this function multiple times. I appreciate any help, also am hoping I won't have to dive too far into jQuery.

This is my Javascript code:

```
    function addZero(i) {
    if(i < 10){
        i = "0" + i;
    };
    return i;
};

    var d = new Date();
        var h = addZero(d.getHours());
        var m = addZero(d.getMinutes());
        var text = "Press left arrow";
            var combo = h + ":" + m;


var isRight=false;
    document.onkeyup=function(e){
        if(e.which == 39) isRight=false;     
    };document.onkeydown=function(e){
        if (e.which == 39) isRight=true;

        if(isRight == true){
                document.getElementById('Time_Shortcut').innerHTML = combo + "<br>" + text;
                return false;
            } else if(e.which == 37){
                document.getElementById('Time_Shortcut').style.display = "none";
            };
    };
```

My HTML code

```
<p id="Time_Shortcut"></p>
```

and just for the heck of it, the CSS that goes with it.

```
    #Time_Shortcut {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: .3;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Times, Serif;
    color: #BD3A26;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    left: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
    #Time_Shortcut:hover {
        opacity: .45;
    }
```

Thank you for the time, and sorry ahead of time if I messed anything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the p tag in the HTML use a div and give it a name then reference your div in your function so the time shows up there. When you want to display make the div visible true when you want to hide make the div visible false. Ive added a solution in html with embedded script and css.

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
////////////////////////
///// create a div /////
////////////////////////
document.write('<div id="time" style="position: absolute; visibility:hidden; overflow:hidden; z-index=2; width: 200; height: 100; top:100; left:100; padding:0"></div>');

/////////////////////////////////////
///// set backgtound of div red /////
/////////////////////////////////////
time.style.backgroundColor="#ff0000";

///////////////////////////////////////////////
///// keyboard event listner              /////
///// on keypress goto function disptime /////
//////////////////////////////////////////////

document.onkeypress = disptime;

/////////////////////////////
///// function disptime /////
/////////////////////////////
function disptime(e) {

///////////////////////////////////////////
///// get the charcode of key pressed /////
///////////////////////////////////////////

    evt = e || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;

///////////////////////////////////////////
///// if up or down arrow key pressed /////
///////////////////////////////////////////
if (charCode==38)
{
    var d = new Date();

    var curr_hour = d.getHours();
    var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
    var c2 = document.getElementById("time");
    c2.style.visibility='visible';  
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=(curr_hour + ":" + curr_min);
}

if (charCode==40)
{
    var c2 = document.getElementById('time');
    c2.style.visibility='hidden';   

}
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Everything worked as shown, I just had to change it from document.onkeypress = disptime; to document.onkeydown = disptime; thank you so much, you saved me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from your description, you would like to detect a key press while on a webpage and then have a java function do something and return that something to the webpage.

Can you take me through the steps a user would do and the results a user would see to fully understand your question please.

Comment: Basically, it currently is set up so there is nothing when you open the page but, if you press the right arrow key it will open up the time in hours and minutes and if you press the left arrow key it will go back to not displaying anything. That works perfectly but after I hit the left arrow key to make it display nothing I can't press the right key to make it display the time again. I need help trying to figure out how to loop those two. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Glad it worked out and good luck with your project. Can someone please close this as answered and give me some points. Thanks